# Join query confusion - I don't know how to join the 3 queries

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, join

First query:

```
select 
    pid, month(dates) as month, sum(quan) as quan 
from 
    purchase 
where 
    month(dates) between 1 and 12 
    and pid = 4 
group by 
    pid, month(dates)
```

Second query:

```
select 
    pid, month(dates) as months, sum(quan) as TotalAmount 
from 
    inward 
where 
    month(dates) between 1 and 12 
    and pid = 4 
group by 
    pid, month(dates)
```

Third query:

```
select 
    pid, month(dates) as months, sum(quan) as TotalAmount 
from 
    issue 
where 
    month(dates) between 1 and 12 
    and pid = 4 
group by 
    pid, month(dates)
```

I don't know how to join these queries for output pid is foreign key

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Oracle? MySQL? SQL Server? ...

Comment: SQl server is in use

Answer (score 0):

Try using the join statement

```
SELECT
pid,month(dates) AS month,sum(quan) AS quan 
FROM purchase 
    INNER Join
pid,month(dates) AS months , sum(quan) AS TotalAmount
FROM inward
    INNER JOIN
pid,month(dates) AS months , sum(quan) AS TotalAmount
FROM issue
WHERE month(dates) between 1 and 12 AND pid=4
GROUP BY pid, month(dates)
```

Comment: its showing error message like this --Incorrect syntax near ','.

Answer (score 0):

Join the three queries as if they were tables. You need parentheses around them, i.e. `from (...) join (...)`:

```
select
  pid, 
  month,
  coalesce(sum_purchase.total, 0) as total_purchase,
  coalesce(sum_inward.total, 0) as total_inward,
  coalesce(sum_issue.total, 0) as total_issue
from
(
  select pid, month(dates) as month, sum(quan) as total
  from purchase 
  where pid=4 
  group by pid, month(dates)
) sum_purchase
full outer join
(
  select pid, month(dates) as month, sum(quan) as total
  from inward 
  where pid=4 
  group by pid, month(dates)
) sum_inward using (pid, month)
full outer join
(
  select pid, month(dates) as month, sum(quan) as total
  from issue 
  where pid=4 
  group by pid, month(dates)
) sum_issue using (pid, month)
order by pid, month;
```

This is standard SQL and should work in many DBMS. Some don't support full outer joins however, others don't support using clauses. So you may have to adjust this a little.